# Find special character # between '<' and '>' inside text

Tags: regex

I'm stuck with finding `#` which is between <...> in below text:

```
bhdfgkkd#?gdsjkngfds/<1743610374#deliveryCustomerAck-2092288912_1638264514789@f106>
```

I am able to return text inside <...> `1743610374#deliveryCustomerAck-2092288912_1638264514789@f106` using
regex

```
(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)
```

but how to return only `#`?

PS I will use this regex in Java

Update: done, answer below. Thx for help.

Comment: What you are doing and where (what is the tool/programming language)?

Comment: In the title is says http link, but there is not http in the string so your pattern does not take that in to account.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with regex this is not important with tool / programming language you have

Comment: @Thefourthbird sry I forgot to modify title after modified text for regex

Comment: It does. Why do you want to capture a known char in between `<` and `>`? Also, `(?<=\<).*?(#).*?(?=\>)` does not only return `#`. Also, it will find `#` in `<a> # <b>` - is `#` still between `<` and `>` here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's not important why :) Have a special requirement for app that I create

Comment: @Thefourthbird WiktorStribiżew  I fix description to be more clear. Thx guys for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct. Wrap the `#` inside a group so that you can retrieve it later with group number 1 in your language of choice.

```
(?<=\<).*?(#).*?(?=\>)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eotWeF/1)

Comment: There is a catch here that the pattern does not take angle brackets into account using the `.*?` See https://regex101.com/r/Ih7GFg/1

Comment: I think `(?<=<[^<>]*)#(?=[^<>]*>)` or `<[^<>]*(#)[^<>]*>` would be better.

Comment: Besides, what good is capturing a known char in this regex without code? Also, `\<` and `\>` are POSIX-like word boundaries, there is no need escaping literal `<` and `>` in any regex.